# How to reschedule Apache Camel Quartz (CronScheduledRoutePolicy) endpoint route on failure

Tags: java, spring, maven, apache-camel, quartz-scheduler

This is my schedular(CronScheduledRoutePolicy) for data processing.

```
    <route>
        <from uri="quartz://schedule?cron=0+1+0+*+*+?+*"/>
        <bean ref="processData" method="scheduleData" />
            <convertBodyTo type="java.util.List" />
            <to uri="activemq:queue:DATA.GENERATEDLIST?mapJmsMessage=false" />

        <onException>
            <exception>java.lang.Exception</exception>
            <to uri="activemq:queue:DATA.ERROR.MESSAGES?mapJmsMessage=false&amp;jmsMessageType=Text" />
        </onException>
    </route>
```

It runs everyday 12.01 am, the question is if any error occurs how to re-run or re-schedule manually using schedule id or route id.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you please clarify the question - if the route fails, is it that you want to be able to manually re-run the route?

Comment: Yes i need to do manually. Because i am using multiple datasource and for some scheduler input is based on time.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, since you have clarified your question, you need 2 ways to be able to do your data processing: firstly via the cron schedule and then manually.

I am going to suggest you break it into 3 routes (this is obviously java DSL, but you can easily convert it to xml).

1. First route is the quartz schedule- it calls the processing route.

   ```
   from("quartz://schedule?cron=0+1+0+*+*+?+*")
       .to("direct:doProcessing")
   ;
   ```
2. Second route does the processing

   ```
   from("direct:doProcessing")
       // do awesome stuff here...
   ;
   ```
3. Third route is your manual restart

   ```
   from("timer://manualRestart?repeatCount=1")
       .routeId("manualRestart")
       .noAutoStartup()
       .to("direct:doProcessing")
   ;
   ```

Now, you can start the route with id "manualRestart" using the `route-start` command on the command line, or via a tool like `fmc`.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [re-delivery policy](http://camel.apache.org/redeliverypolicy.html) to re-try the exchange N times if an exception is encountered.

```
<route>
    <!-- ... -->
    <onException>
        <exception>java.lang.Exception</exception>
        <redeliveryPolicy redeliveryDelay="100000" maximumRedeliveries="3"/>
        <to uri="activemq:queue:DATA.ERROR.MESSAGES?mapJmsMessage=false&amp;jmsMessageType=Text" />
    </onException>
</route>
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. I need a run the schedule manually either based on scheduler name or route id via a UI. Is it possible because...

Comment: @SureshkumarPanneerselvan I don't know of an easy out-of-the-box way of doing that. You could forward a failed exchange to a dead letter queue, write a client to show them to you, ask for your input and then send a "command" message via MQ to your component, then trigger your route based on the command message.

Comment: Ya we can do that. Thanks.